# Upgraded to 23.04 and issues with shell themes

Tags: gnome, themes, gnome-shell-extension

My current theme is sweet dark, with [this extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/19/user-themes/) to help me set that theme for my whole desktop and the shell.

Back in 22.10, it was going fine. My chrome still looks fine, as you can see the top section the themes are still present

[image]

But if I switch to Discord App the theme isn't present, unlike 22.10

[image]

Confirmed with random apps too;

[image]

[image]

I also verified that my tweaks had the right settings

[image]

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 2):

I guess this shell theme wasn't ready for new Gnome 44 version. You will have to update it when there will be an update for it (I'm also waiting).